# how can I preserve my class after list clear

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 classes

```
public class Product
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Campaign
{
    public long CampaignId { get; set; }
    public string CampaignName { get; set; }            
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
var campaign = new Campaign();
campaign.CampaignId = Item.CampaignId;
campaign.CampaignId = Item.CampaignId;
campaign.CampaignName = Item.CampaignName;                    
campaign.Products = productList;

campaignList.Add(campaign);
productList.Clear();
```

When I call `productList.Clear()`, my "campaign" deletes its `campaign.Products`.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Please add your complete code. What is campaignList,productList ?

Comment: Think campaign.Products = productList; is being assigned by reference. Need to create a new list and populate it with productList and then assign that to campaign.Products

Comment: `campaign.Products = productList.ToList()` should do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
campaign.Products = new List<Product>(productList);
```

Answer (score 3):

because campaign.Products is the same reference of productList
they are both pointing to the same list , any action on one will be reflected in the other varialbe
you need to clone (make another copy of the list) by different ways as follwoing

```
campaign.Products = productList.GetClone();
```

or

```
campaign.Products = productList.ToList();
```

or

```
campaign.Products.AddRange(productList);
```

check the following url

https://www.techiedelight.com/clone-list-in-csharp/